# Creating Micorosft Office Outlook message programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I want to create the Microsoft Office Outlook message programmatically...

i.e. the .msg file

Is it feasible? If yes, how?

I know about `System.Net.Mail` namespace and can create an object of MailMessage class. But how can I create a .msg file using this object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the Outlook Interop. See these [Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268731(VS.80).aspx). Be warned it's [not a good idea](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) to try this via automation however.